# Setting up PDF.js to work with Meteor + Reactjs project (want to use text layer)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, pdf.js

I've been working on a project using Meteor and React, which needs a PDF viewer with the ability to select text.

I'm currently trying to achieve this with Mozilla's PDF.js, but am having some trouble getting started. I'm a long time reader, first time asker at stackoverflow.

I've installed PDF.js with npm.

```
npm install pdfjs-dist --save
```

Now I'm trying to modify the example from pdf.js's github project [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/pageviewer.js) to create a React component that will render a PDF from a supplied file path and include a text layer.

**imports/ui/components/PDF/PDFText.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

require ('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.combined');
require ('pdfjs-dist/web/compatibility');

export default class PDFText extends React.Component {

  renderPDF() {

    PDFJS.workerSrc = '/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';

    const container = document.getElementById('pdf-container');
    const scale = 1;
    const pageNumber = 1;

    PDFJS.getDocument(this.props.file).then(function(pdf) {

      return pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        var pdfPageView = new PDFJS.PDFPageView({
          container: container,
          id: pageNumber,
          scale: scale,
          defaultViewport: page.getViewport(scale),
          textLayerFactory: new PDFJS.DefaultTextLayerFactory()
        });

        pdfPageView.setPdfPage(page);
        return pdfPageView.draw();
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    this.renderPDF()
    return (
      <div id='pdf-container'></div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I include this component in page I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: PDFJS.DefaultTextLayerFactory is not a constructor

The next thing I tried was including 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer' in my code, as this is where DefaultTextLayerFactory is declared. I modified the code above to add the following line above the class declaration:

```
require ('pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer');
```

When I run the code now, I get a different error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PDFJS' of undefined
>
> > ```
> > at Object.<anonymous> (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114918)
> > at __w_pdfjs_require__ (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114838)
> > at Object.<anonymous> (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:117449)
> > at __w_pdfjs_require__ (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114838)
> > at Object.<anonymous> (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:118157)
> > at __w_pdfjs_require__ (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114838)
> > at module.exports (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114884)
> > at modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114887
> > at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114811)
> > at pdf_viewer.js (modules.js?hash=9dd20a3…:114818)
> > ```

I'm really unsure what is going on here. I noticed that the function complaining refers to webpack - which I haven't been using.

I've also tried including the following check at the start of my code (this is taken from pageviewer.js in the github link above).

```
if (!PDFJS.PDFViewer || !PDFJS.getDocument) {
  alert('Please build the pdfjs-dist library using\n' +
        '  `gulp dist`');
}
```

My code does in fact trigger that alert (PDFJS.PDFViewer is undefined) but the message doesn't seem correct as I installed the built pdfjs-dist library using npm. That message seems for people who cloned the repo. There isn't a gulp file in the pdfjs-dist directory - which makes sense.

I'm sure part of thep problem is that I'm experimenting with a lot of new tools here. This is my first time working with meteor, react, node, and pdf.js, so apologies in advance if I've made an obvious rookie mistake.

For the record I've tried a few other libraries, including:

- mikecousins/react-pdf-js (worked reasonably well for simply displaying a pdf with no text layer).
- peerlibrary/meteor-pdf.js (I hit some errors with this one as well, and I didn't pursue it too much further as the repo hasn't been touched in a couple of years).

Hopefully that's enough information for someone to spot the issue. My theory is that there's some other set up step I need to do to get this working for meteor or react (and that's why it hasn't been obvious from the "getting started" in the PDF.js website.

Also, I'm not locked in to PDF.js, so if the easiest solution to my problem is to use something else, I'd be happy to try that.

Thanks for your time

Comment: ditch pdf.combined.js and use require in following order: `require ('pdfjs-dist/web/compatibility'); require ('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'); require ('pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer');` the last one contains DefaultTextLayerFactory

Comment: I just tried that then. I hit one of the errors I described above:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PDFJS' of undefined**

Same stack trace as above.

Comment: I've managed to move a bit further now. I have a rough idea what the problem was. Once I understand it a bit more I'll post an answer here in case anyone else hits the same problem.

Comment: @CampbellDavis I'm trying to use pdfjs at the moment and running into similar issues. Did you end up getting it to work well?

Comment: @CampbellDavis I'm running into the same error. Pls share your solution ;) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many years later, this answer would have been appreciated still